# Splunk - General Queries

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I have some general queries on Splunk, as no one on my team has deep technical knowledge & I've never used it before, appreciate anyone's help on this, thanks

I have the following Splunk query

```
(host = "A" OR host = "B" OR host = "C" OR host = "D" OR host = "E" OR host = "F" OR host = "G" OR host = "H") 
AND source = "logs/BAU.log"

| transaction submission_id startswith="ABC Logic begins" endswith="ABC Logic ended"

| eval group = case(host IN ("A", "B", "C", "D"), "Primary",
                    host IN ("E", "F", "G", "H"), "Secondary")

| chart dc(submission_id) by group
```

If process ABC fails, the log "ABC Logic ended" will not be displayed, instead "ABC Logic failed" is logged.

In the following log example, will my query return a count of 2 or 3?

```
INFO [BkndDriver]--[submission_id=1] ABC Logic begins
...
INFO [BkndDriver]--[submission_id=1] ABC Logic failed
...
...
...
INFO [BkndDriver]--[submission_id=2] ABC Logic begins
...
INFO [BkndDriver]--[submission_id=2] ABC Logic ended
...
...
INFO [BkndDriver]--[submission_id=3] ABC Logic begins
...
INFO [BkndDriver]--[submission_id=3] ABC Logic ended
```

We are experiencing some inaccuracies with the total count of calls made to the ABC service, I am trying to troubleshoot what may be causing the mismatch in the total count.

Because I've structured my query to look for the specific strings "ABC Logic begins" & "ABC Logic ended", I'm not sure if I should change the query to use a different command?

Comment: change the endsWith criteria to look for either ended or failed: `endswith="ABC Logic ended" OR "ABC Logic failed"`

Comment: and if you are going to use `IN` to produce the group field, why not also use it in the initial query selecting items? `host IN ("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H") AND source="logs/BAU.log"`

Comment: @MadsHansen - even better, drop the "`AND`", since Splunk ANDs by default :)